# Depending on a generated file

Tags: shake-build-system

What's the right way for a rule to `need` a generated file? Here's what I tried:

```
import Development.Shake
import System.IO
import Control.Monad

main = do
    s <- withBinaryFile "/dev/urandom" ReadMode $ replicateM 10 . hGetChar

    shakeArgs shakeOptions $ do
        want ["a.out"]

        "generated" *> \target -> writeFileChanged target s

        "*.out" *> \out -> do
            need ["generated"]
            writeFile' out =<< readFile' "generated"
```

But this results in the rule for `generated` not getting re-run, so `a.out` stays the same after repeated runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to add `alwaysRerun` to the definition of `generated`, so that the `generated` rule always runs. You are correctly depending on `generated` with the `need` (and also with the `readFile'`, which does a `need` behind scenes), it's just that `generated` doesn't have any input dependencies, so never gets rerun. Adding `alwaysRerun` gives `generated` a dependency that always changes. I would expect to see:

```
"generated" *> \target -> do
    alwaysRerun
    writeFileChanged target s
```

(You can also move the definition of `s` down to under `generated`, but I have a suspicion that's just an artefact of how you've simplified your test case.)

Comment: Yes indeed, both the `writeFile'` implementation of the `"*.out"` rule and the generation of `"generated"` are stubs standing in for more involved operations.